# Cakephp 2.0 Ajax post data not showing in the controller?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, controller, default

I'm working cakephp web application, I have created a small `Ajax function` in `default ctp file`. setup file now I want to send value data to another controller function, in the `chrome browser network` showing that Ajax posting to desire url but in controller post value didn't show up when I try to echo `$_post ['selectedlocation']`??

**Ajax Default File**

```
var DisplayLocationName = $('#ListingLocation option:selected').val();

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/listings/home',
     data: {selectedlocation:DisplayLocationName },
     dataType:"text",
     success: function(result) {

     }
     });
```

**Listing Controller Function**

```
function home()
{

    if(!isset($this->params['requested']) || $this->params['requested'] != true)
    {
        $this->actionId = 'home';
    }

    $this->viewFile = null;

    if($this->params['isAjax'] &&  isset($_POST['selectedlocation'])) 
    {

            echo "erreerreer";
            echo $selectloc= $_POST['selectedlocation'];
            $this->set('selectloc',$selectloc); 

    }

}
```

how do I display Ajax post value in default for testing purposes that, make sure me that Ajax is posting proper values to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the logging files to read the post data. This will write the data to the error log and you can view it there.

```
function home()
{

    if(!isset($this->params['requested']) || $this->params['requested'] != true)
    {
        $this->actionId = 'home';
    }

    $this->viewFile = null;

    if($this->params['isAjax'] &&  isset($_POST['selectedlocation'])) 
    {

            echo "erreerreer";
            CakeLog::write('error', $this->request->data('selectedlocation));
            echo $selectloc= $_POST['selectedlocation'];
            $this->set('selectloc',$selectloc); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to $_POST a data from an ajax request, you should use:

```
$form_data = $this->request->data; (cakephp 2.x)
$form_data = $this->params['form'] (cakephp 1.3)
```

Now you got an array with your $_POSTed data, try to var_dump() it to understand its sctructure if you want.

Comment: if im not using form than?

Comment: try: $this->data['selectedlocation'];